# Burning my time

Tags: riddle, word

> All by myself,
>
> left behind,
>
> only me here,
>
> nobody to find,
>
> envy of others.

What am I?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are

> alone.

This doesn't only fit the riddle lines, but also

> the first letters of each line spell "alone".

Comment: indeed I am T_T

Comment: @user7393973 Even though you might just be // I hope that you don't feel lonely :P

Answer (score 6):

Are you:

> Death or dead?

All by myself,

> Death, generally, takes one person at a time

left behind,

> When you die, people move on

only me here,

> Only you in the coffin, no one else

nobody to find,

> A body may be found, but it's lifeless (obviously)

envy of others.

> People in tough spots wish for death - "I wish I was dead!"

"Hidden"

> Alone - everyone dies alone

Comment: You clearly put more effort into this than I did ;-)

Comment: @Christoph I thought about answering the same way, but it seemed a little **too** obvious :P